# Multiple ctrl + c freezes program

Tags: bash, sigint

I have a "main" bash script that runs another bash script (23.sh).
In the main script, I have a function that catches <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> operations and prompts for a password.  If password is entered correctly, then it kills the main file.

However, I have an issue: when the user enters <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> twice in quick succession, the script freezes up (see comments in script below).

How do I deal with this? In essence, I would like the function ctrl_c() to be recursive so that when a user uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when within the function, it still takes effect.  I remember from a long time ago (some 10 years) that I was told that recursion in fuctions is a **bad idea!**  Any solution?

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is the main file that runs data collection code 23.sh in an infinite loop

function ctrl_c() {
    clear
    echo "** Trapped CTRL-C0"
    sleep 1s
    echo "'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''"
    echo "Enter Admin password and click [ENTER]: "
    # When user enters ctrl+c in here the program freezes up
    read passPhrase
    if [ $passPhrase == "pass" ]; then
        echo "Password correct"

        for i in `seq 1 5`; do
            sleep 1
            echo -n "."
            # pkill 23.sh
            # pkill main.sh
        done
        pkill main.sh
    else
        echo "Incorrect pass phrase.  'Service Selection' screen will in 5 seconds load"
        for i in `seq 1 5`; do
            sleep 1
            echo -n "."
        done
        # ./23.sh
    fi
}

trap ctrl_c INT

while :
do
    ./23.sh
done
```

Comment: I do not see the behavior that you describe.  At the "Enter Admin password..." prompt, if I issue a `Ctrl-C` then the script terminates.

Comment: @AndyDalton What diagnostics would you recommend I run?  I still have this issue.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want.  It looks like when the signal handler is invoked, the handler is reset to the default handler.  When I issue `Ctrl-C` again, the script terminates.  If I re-register the signal handler within the handler function, then the script does not respond to `Ctrl-C` while the signal handler is running (but also doesn't terminate).  In no case do I see the script "freeze".

Comment: @AndyDalton So what I am doing now, to fix this is to change the siginthandler from ^C to a different key combo ussing `stty`.  This seems to work as "mischievous" users do not know what key to use to terminate the program.  This is not the best solution, but it works.  Do you have a suggestion on how to have a more robust ^C/sigterm/sigint handler?